# Find user id by username [aiogram]

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, aiogram

How can I find out the user id by his username? I use the aiogram library and I have not found information on the Internet how to do this. Is there any method?

```
import logging

from configparser import ConfigParser
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

config = ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

TOKEN = config.get('BOT', 'Token')

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    text = config.get('BOT_TEXT', 'Start')
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text)


@dp.message_handler()
async def forward(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(message.forward_from.id, 'Kuku')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup

username = ''
answer = 0

class Name(StatesGroup):
get_message = State()

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'], state=get_message)
async def get_message(self: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    global username
    global answer
    answer = self.from_id
    await state.finish()
    ...
    await bot.send_message(self.from_user.id, f'Your id: {answer}')
```

You will receive the from_id
Don't forget to install fsm

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [ReplyKeyboardMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#replykeyboardmarkup) with a [KeyboardButtonRequestChat](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#keyboardbuttonrequestchat)
After that just send the contact over to your bot using the ReplyKeyboardMarkup you've created, handle the shared chat & fetch the user_id.

As far as I remember it should be something like this:

```py
from aiogram.types import ContentTypes, Message

@dp.message_handler(content_types=[ContentType.CHAT_SHARED])
async def fetch_user_id(message: Message):
     user_id = message.chat_shared.chat_id
     return user_id
```

⚠️ Caution, I didn't test the code, but as far as I remember, it should work like this in aiogram 2.*